# Array Index Out of Bounds exception 1>=1

Tags: java, arrays

I am sending data from jtable to database and it is working perfectly but i dont know why it raise an error that Array Index Out Of Bounds 1>=1
or Array Index Out Of Bounds 1>=1

Here is my code

```
public void save()
{
    try
    {
    String Date[] =new String[10];
    String Bill_No[] =new String[10];
    String M_Id[] =new String[10];
    String C_Name[] =new String[10]; // C_Name is array and index 10 means no. of row
    String Item_No[]=new String[10];
    String Product[]=new String[10];
    String Price[] =new String[10];
    String Quantity[] =new String[10];
    String Amount[] =new String[10];
    String Points[] = new String[10];

    for(int i=0; i<12; i++) //loop from 0 row to 10
    {
    Date[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,0).toString(); // it get value from 0 row and 0 column
    Bill_No[i] =jTable1.getValueAt(i,1).toString();
    M_Id[i] =jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
    C_Name[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,3).toString();  // it get value from 0 row and 1 column
    Item_No[i] =jTable1.getValueAt(i,4).toString();
    Product[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,5).toString();
    Price[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,6).toString();
    Quantity[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,7).toString();
    Amount[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,8).toString();
    Points[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,9).toString();

   //similarly for more column  
    try
    {
        s=conn.createStatement();
        int row=s.executeUpdate( "insert into E_Costumes values('"+Date[i]+"','"+Bill_No[i]+"','"+M_Id[i]+"','"+C_Name[i]+"','"+Item_No[i]+"','"+Product[i]+"','"+Price[i]+"','"+Quantity[i]+"','"+Amount[i]+"','"+Points[i]+"')");
        if(row>0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ITEM ADDED SUCCESSFULLY.");
            quantity_sub();
        }
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);

    }
    }
}    
catch(Exception ex)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);
}

}
```

Comment: Your for loop should be `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<12; i++)//0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
                                              |  |
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
               But for index 10 and 11 your arrays don't have element 
               because all arrays will have elements from 0....to...9
```

If all array will have same length than you should declare length as a constant,

```
private static final int COMMON_ARRAY_LENGHT = 10;
```

and use that in every array initialization as well as in loop,

```
String Date[] =new String[COMMON_ARRAY_LENGHT];
//..And so on
```

At the same time your loop will be,

```
for(int i=0; i < COMMON_ARRAY_LENGHT; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array size which you are providing is String C_Name[] =new String[10]; in which you can add only from 0 to 9.
While you are trying to add elements in array beyond its index.

or for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
will solve your problem
please check updated answer

Comment: `for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)` will not solve the problem (it should be `i<10`) and `for(int i=-;i<10;i++)` doesn't even compile.